# Convert flat list elements into nested collection in java

Tags: java, collections, group-by

I have a list of elements and I need to group by certain elements of this list type and convert it to a nested collection. Here is what I mean-

Consider below -

```
class StudentA {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int subjectId;
    private String subjectName;
}

class StudentB {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    List<Subject> subject;
}

class Subject {
    private int subjectId;
    private String subjectName;
}
```

I have a `List<StudentA>` as my input. But in this list each student can have multiple subjects and hence student information is repeating (for eg: `[new StudentA("A",22,1,"X"), new StudentA("A",22,2,"Y"), new StudentA("B",24,1,"X") ]` and so on).
This is not a good representation and I need data in below format-

```
List<StudentB>
```

Note that StudentB has list of Subject as an element.

Here is what i am thinking, but not convinced,

- Plain old iterative way where I iterate through each element in
  original list and construct what I need
- I also looked at java8
  stream api which has groupby on collected data which looks promising,
  but i can't seem to convert from StudentA type in the list to my
  StudentB type

What would be a good and efficient way to perform this ? Thanks much !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you group instances of `StudentA` by name, you'll get a `Map<String,List<StudentA>>`. Then you can stream the values of this map and convert them to instances of `StudentB`:

```
List<StudentB> bList =
    aList.stream() // Stream<StudentA>
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StudentA::getName)) // Map<String,List<StudentA>>
         .values() // Collection<List<StudentA>>
         .stream() // Stream<List<StudentA>>
         .map(list -> {
             StudentB b = new StudentB();
             b.setName(list.get(0).getName());
             b.setAge(list.get(0).getAge());
             list.forEach(a -> b.addSubject(new Subject(a.getSubjectID(),a.getSubjectName())));
             return b;
         }) // Stream<StudentB>
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I took the liberty of assuming the existence of some method names and constructors.

This solution has the downside of potentially creating multiple `Subject` instances for the same `Subject`. This can be avoided if you create a `Map<Integer,Subject>` that contains the `Subject`s indexed by their IDs, and only create new `Subject`s if the required subject ID is not already in that `Map`.

Comment: Thank you ! Exactly what I was looking for. And on, creating multiple instances of Subject for the same Subject, that is fine. I am not dealing with thousands here

Comment: Wonderful example !